# How to handle null value in a table column with data type float

Tags: java, floating-point

I have a table "hit", with a column data_value with float data type (default value: NULL):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hit`;
CREATE TABLE  `hit` (
  `hit_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `data_value` float default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`hit_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How should I handle this in java when I do: getDataValue()? I'd like it to return NULL if the value is null, but it returns 0.0.
Thanks,

David

Comment: I assume you're trying to read a `float` instead of a `Float`, don't you? Try changing that and you should get `null` instead of `0.0`.

Comment: java class for this table is automatically generated by an ORM library (Torque, namely), getDataValue() returns double, in turn 0.0 for null entries. I know I can have another method to return Double instead of double, is this the best way of handling this situation?

Comment: Yes, you need to return a wrapper object instead of a primitive, since there are no null values for primitives.

Comment: thanks, and another question related (sorry): since double getDataValue() is from super class I can't change and I can't override  it to return a Double object, I'm creating a new method called: Double getDataValueObject(), but I also want to override the getDataValue() in a way to warn others to use getDataValueObject() instead, how do I do that? thanks!

Comment: Well, you could throw an `OperationNotSupportedException` in order to warn them at runtime. Additionally, you could override the method and annotate it as deprecated to provide a hint when writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the uppercase Java classes instead of the primitive, e.g.:

- Float instead of float
- Double instead of double
- BigDecimal

Primitives can't take the value `null`, they always default to 0 instead. The classes will allow you to use `null` as well.